# How can i manipulate dropdown values from .ts file in ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have created on form with dependent drop-downs and some input fields.I want it working in 2 scenarios

1. Initially if the session is null then there should be no data in the form and     all the fields should be blank by default.(which i have created)
2. If there is session then i'm pulling data in JSON format from a Web API and then i want to fill the fields accordingly.

---

```
     <ion-item>
        <ion-label>State</ion-label>
        <ion-select (ionChange)="setCountyValues(sState)" [(ngModel)]="sState" >
          <ion-option [value]="sState" *ngFor="let sState of states" [selected]="sState">{{sState.name}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item *ngIf="selectedCounties">
        <ion-label>Counties</ion-label>
        <ion-select (ionChange)="setCityValues(sCounty)" [(ngModel)]="sCounty">
          <ion-option [value]="sCounty" *ngFor="let sCounty of selectedCounties">{{sCounty.name}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item *ngIf="selectedCities">
        <ion-label>Cities</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="sCity">
          <ion-option [value]="sCity" *ngFor="let sCity of selectedCities">{{sCity.name}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item *ngIf="selectedCities">
        <button ion-button round color="primary" (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
        <button ion-button round color="primary" (click)="goToOfficeDetail()">Office Detail Page</button>
      </ion-item>

<ion-item>
    <button ion-button round color="primary" (click)="Autofill()">Autofill</button>   </ion-item>
```

---

```
[{
    "PageRec":"AL005",
    "State":"AL",
    "County":"Autauga County",
    "CityTown":null,
    "Zip":null,
    "ShowRecordingInfo":"true",
    "Deed":{
        "Checked":"True",
        "Pages":"1",
        "ConsiderationAmount":"150000"
        },
    "MortgageDeed":{
        "Checked":"False",
        "Pages":null,
        "NewDebtAmount":null
        },
    "MortgageRefi":{
        "Checked":"False",
        "Pages":null,
        "NewDebtAmount":null,
        "OriginalDebt":null,
        "UnpaidDebt":null
        },
    "Assignment":{
        "Checked":"False",
        "Pages":null,
        "Assignments":null
        },
    "ReleaseSatisfaction":{
        "Checked":"False",
        "Pages":null,
        "ReleasesSatisfactions":null
        },
    "Questions":{
        "Question":{
            "Number":"Q4",
            "Category":"Deed",
            "Type":"bool",
            "Question Text":"Are the deed and ``mortgage being recorded at the same time?",
            "Answer":"1"
            }
        }
}]
```

.TS

```
   GetDocumentDetailsData()
  {
    this.zipcode.getDocDetails().then(data=>this.documentDetails=data); 
  }

 Autofill()
  {

    this.GetDocumentDetailsData();

     this.sState = this.documentDetails.State;

  }
```

My Issue is when i am trying to fill drop-down then why is showing issue saying cannot find property "State" of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple problems. What you are receiving is an array, so `documentDetails` contains an array and therefore `documentDetails.State` cannot be found. So you need to change it to `documentDetails[0].State`

And then I'd do the request just like this:

```ts
AutoFill() {
   this.zipcode.getDocDetails()
      .then(data=> {
         this.documentDetails=data;
         this.sState = this.documentDetails[0].state;
      }); 
}
```

Then the next problem occurs, Angular cannot distinguish and connect `sState` with the corresponding `name` property in your object in the `states` array. So you need to create reference to it. That also means that `sState` becomes an object just like the objects you have in your array.

So this can be done in the callback as well:

```ts
.then(data=> {
   this.documentDetails=data;
   this.sState = this.states.find(state => state.name == this.documentDetails[0].State)
});
```

Here's a **[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/lhnddGj1KcCwCg1V3Lm8?p=preview)** (ionic 2). I've used Observables instead of Promises, but that doesn't really matter ;)

---

**EDIT:**

If the case is, that you are not getting predefined value to `sState`, and it is `undefined`, like mentioned in comments, it ticks all option. I could not reproduce the issue with the ionic 2 (RC) version I was using as demo, but in ionic 3 it could be reproduced. What seems to solve this fine, is to initialize `sState` as an empty object in the component:

```ts
sState = {};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @AJT_82..it's working fine now in case if i had something in session...But if its a fresh user then it should be blank.But now i have [selected]="sState" which would choose everything when there is no single state in sState...Should i be writing separate *ngIf for it or is there any other better solution to it?

Comment: What do mean with ***But now i have [selected]="sState" which would choose everything when there is no single state in sState*** what does it choose, it shouldn't choose anything if `sState` has no preset value?

Comment: yes...so when there is no data in sState it's selecting everything...like 4 ticks are coming at once if i am having 4 entries in states

Comment: @priyankbhardwaj What ***ticks***? No such things in the code presented. I don't understand at all :D Could you fork my plunker and showcase the problem and I can help much better! :)

Comment: Ah, now I think I understand what you mean with ticks :D Well, what is the content of `sState` if there is no preset data? It shouldn't tick everything if there is no data in `sState`: http://plnkr.co/edit/JukZa3vK40l6iNHsQuBz?p=preview So I suggest you fork plunker and reproduce the issue there :)

Comment: @AJT_82...i updated the plunk but it's not giving the same issue as mine although the code is the same.. :( ...Something somewhere i am messing it up

Comment: @priyankbhardwaj Hmm... have you checked what your `sState` has as value if you are not receiving data? Do you always run the http-request in this component? What is it receiving in case there actually is no data? I mean it's probably returning *something* though which shows us there is nothing to set to `sState`?

Comment: @AJT_82...i removed [selected]="sState" and it started working fine...Now  i am totally not understanding this ionic's behavior :(

Comment: @priyankbhardwaj check updated answer, I managed to reproduce it with ionic 3. Initialize the object and it should clear it out?

Comment: Problem: http://plnkr.co/edit/1xwhtwB5YjKHDbRzusHP?p=preview Solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/ULVC8jqcaT1PXWkucKMP?p=preview If in case there is a request and it then becomes `undefined` (again). Just make an if-statement inside your `then`.. something like: `then(data => {if(!data){this.sState = {}}else{....}})`

Comment: Exactly....you did an amazing demo on this...Once again thanks....Have a great day ahead :D

Answer (score 0):

You are using a *promise* which is asynchronous. You can chain promises in your case to make sure you set `this.sState` *when* `this.documentDetails` is set.

```
  GetDocumentDetailsData()
  {
   return this.zipcode.getDocDetails().then(data=>{
        this.documentDetails=data;
        return data;//return data to receive in the next then
   }); //return the promise
  }

 Autofill()
  {

    this.GetDocumentDetailsData().then(docDetails=>{
         this.sState = docDetails.State;
    }).
      catch(err=>console.log(err));//all errors thrown in chain get caught 

  }
```

Comment: Thanks @suraj... But,It's giving error at docdetails.State itself..Says property State does not  exist on type {}

Comment: @suraj- i tried with docdetais[0].State as well but it is giving the previous issue itself.."Cannot find property State"

Comment: Sounds like you are not receiving any data